# binary search tree impelemntation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement binary search tree but facing some problem
in node insertion.
can any one help me to point out what is wrong in my python program? 
addChild() function is not adding left child (4, "hans") correctly? 
is there problem in my recursive function ?
thanks in advance.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.leftChild = leftChild
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.parent = parent

    def get_key(self):
        return self.key

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_leftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild    

    def get_rightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def set_leftChild(self, key, value):
        node = Node(key, value, None, None, self)
        self.leftChild = node

    def set_rightChild(self, key, value):
        node = Node(key, value, None, None, self)
        self.rightChild = node 

    def isLeaf(self):
        if self.leftChild is None and self.rightChild is None:
           return True
        else:
           return False   

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, key = None, value = None, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None):
        self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)

    def addChild(self, key, value):
        current = self.root
        if current is None:
           current = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
        else:   
           self._addChild(current, key, value)

    def _addChild(self, current, key, value):                
        if current is None:
           current = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = current)
           return 

        if current.isLeaf() is True:
            if current.get_key() > key:
               current.set_leftChild(key, value)
            else:
               current.set_rightChild(key, value)
            return
        elif current.get_key() > key:
                return self._addChild(current.get_leftChild(), key, value) 
        elif current.get_key() <= key:                
                return self._addChild(current.get_rightChild(), key, value)

    def traversalInOrder(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return None 
        else:   
            self._traversalInOrder(self.root)            

obj = BinaryTree(10, "ram")
obj.addChild(12, "hari")
obj.addChild(4, "hans")
```

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to insert? Can you share it with us so we can provide more focused help?

Answer (score 0):

When `current is None`, you don't actually store the value in the tree but only in a local variable.

This way it should work:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addChild(self, key, value):
        current = self.root
        if current is None:
          self.root = Node(key, value, leftChild = None, rightChild = None, parent = None)
        else:  
          self._addChild(current, key, value)

    def _addChild(self, current, key, value):                
        if current.get_key() > key:
          child = current.get_leftChild()
          if child is None:
            current.set_leftChild(key, value)
          else:
            self._addChild(child, key, value) 
        else:
          child = current.get_rightChild()
          if child is None:
            current.set_rightChild(key, value)
          else:
            self._addChild(child, key, value) 


obj = BinaryTree()
obj.addChild(10, "ram")
obj.addChild(12, "hari")
obj.addChild(4, "hans")
```